# How to start an animated SVG on entering viewport?

Tags: javascript, svg

I need some help from you guys. I can't find a good solution to my problem. I got sections in my website with some animated SVGs. I used vivus.js for this. https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/
The problem is that i can't find a solution to start the animation when the user scrolls on the section with the animated SVGs.

Comment: Add please a minimal working code snippet and what you tried yet to achieve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To trigger an animation when the SVG scrolls into view, there are two steps you need to resolve:

1. detect when the SVG is visible
2. have the animation paused initially, then trigger it when you want

### Detecting when an element is visible

You need to add an event handler for scroll events.  In that event handler, you compare the page scroll location (`window.scrollY`) against the SVG's location on the page.  You can get that using `getBoundingClientRect()`.

See the demos below for example code implementing this technique.

### Starting an animation running

The second step is actually triggering the animation at that time.  How you keep an animation paused and then start it running, depends on the method of animation you are using.

**SVG SMIL animation**

In this first example, we are using the SMIL animation elements that are part of the SVG standard.

To have an animation wait for you to start it running, set the `begin` attribute to `"indefinite"`.  The you can start it running by calling `beginElement()` on the `<animate>` element.

```js
// Get the position on the page of the SVG
var svgLocation = document.getElementById("mysvg").getBoundingClientRect();

// Scroll offset that triggers animation start.
// In this case it is the bottom of the SVG.
var offsetToTriggerAnimation = svgLocation.y + svgLocation.height;

// Function to handle the scroll event.
// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
function scrollAnimTriggerCheck(evt)
{
  var viewBottom = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  if (viewBottom > offsetToTriggerAnimation) {
    // Start the SMIL animation
    document.getElementById("anim").beginElement();
    // Remove the event handler so it doesn't trigger again
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
  }
}

// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
```

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll down</p>

<svg id="mysvg">
  <rect x="0" width="150" height="150" fill="rebeccapurple">
    <animate id="anim" attributeName="x" from="0"  to="150" dur="2s"
             fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
</svg>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

**CSS animation**

There are a couple of way you can trigger an animation to start when you are using CSS animations.

1. Put your `animation` property in its own style set class, then add that class to the element:

   ```
    .anim {
      animation-name: slide;
      animation-duration: 2s;
    }

    myobject.classList.add("anim");
   ```

```js
// Get the position on the page of the SVG
var svgLocation = document.getElementById("mysvg").getBoundingClientRect();

// Scroll offset that triggers animation start.
// In this case it is the bottom of the SVG.
var offsetToTriggerAnimation = svgLocation.y + svgLocation.height;

// Function to handle the scroll event.
// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
function scrollAnimTriggerCheck(evt)
{
  var viewBottom = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  if (viewBottom > offsetToTriggerAnimation) {
    // Start the CSS animation by adding the animation CSS rules to the rect element
    document.querySelector("rect").classList.add("anim");;
    // Remove the event handler so it doesn't trigger again
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
  }
}

// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
```

```css
.anim {
  animation: slide 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate(150px, 0px);
  }
}

svg { border: solid 1px grey; }
p { margin-bottom: 1000px; }
```

```html
<p>Scroll down</p>

<svg id="mysvg">
  <rect x="0" width="150" height="150" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
</svg>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

2. The second way is to make use of the `animation-play-state` CSS property. Not all browsers support this yet.

   The idea is that you set `animation-play-state` to `paused` initially, then change it to `running` when you want the animation to start.  You can either do that by adding a class with that property (similar to above). Or you can set the `style.animationPlayState` property directly, as in the example below.

```js
// Get the position on the page of the SVG
var svgLocation = document.getElementById("mysvg").getBoundingClientRect();

// Scroll offset that triggers animation start.
// In this case it is the bottom of the SVG.
var offsetToTriggerAnimation = svgLocation.y + svgLocation.height;

// Function to handle the scroll event.
// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
function scrollAnimTriggerCheck(evt)
{
  var viewBottom = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  if (viewBottom > offsetToTriggerAnimation) {
    // Start the CSS animation by setting the animation-play-state to "running"
    document.querySelector("rect").style.animationPlayState = "running";
    // Remove the event handler so it doesn't trigger again
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
  }
}

// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
```

```css
.anim {
  animation: slide 2s linear forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate(150px, 0px);
  }
}

svg { border: solid 1px grey; }
p { margin-bottom: 1000px; }
```

```html
<p>Scroll down</p>

<svg id="mysvg">
  <rect x="0" width="150" height="150" fill="rebeccapurple" class="anim"/>
</svg>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for a **React** solution, this is what worked for me,
changing the `key` value of an svg elements i wanted re-start the animation of.

For example, I set the key of an svg element as such:

```
           <span
              ref={nameRef}
              className={`underline-animation ${
                nameRefinView ? "in-view" : ""
              }`}
            >
              <svg
               ....
                key={nameKey}  // <----HERE
              >
                <path
                  ....
                />
              </svg>
              Awshaf
            </span>
```

Note: `naneRefinView` is true when `nameRef` comes into viewport, and defined as such:

```
  const [nameRef, nameRefinView] = useInView({
    threshold: 0.6,
    triggerOnce: false,
  });
```

Ref of inView: https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer

Finally I change the `key` every time the element comes into viewport:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!nameRefinView) {
    } else {
      setNameKey(Math.random());
    }
  }, [nameRefinView]);
```

Whenever react's key value changes, it triggers a re-render of the element without a page refresh. That is why when there is a new key, the animation is restarted as the element becomes rendered.
For reference here is the CSS i used for the code above:

```
.underline-animation {
  text-decoration: none; 
  position: relative;
}
.underline-animation svg {
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.underline-animation .stroke {
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: .15em;
  stroke-dasharray: 822;
  stroke-dashoffset: 822;
  animation: underlineAnimation 0.88s 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.55, 0.55, 1) forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  
}

  //==== ANIMATION starts ONLY when the element is in view port====
    .underline-animation.in-view .stroke {
      animation-play-state: running; /* Start animation when in view */
    }
```